# JQuery click function Works only on first click

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is a screen scrape function that I want to click all of the links that are stored in `$el`. The first call to the click function works and I have confirmed all the links are stored in `$el`.
On the next call to click I get the error

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'document' of null".

What I would like it to do is to loop through all the links in $el and click on each.

```
var workflow = {

    preScrape: function(request, callBack) {

        console.log("starting Pre-scrape hook NOW");
        var waitTime = 2; // Wait for n seconds 
        var $el = $("h3>a"); // Element to click 

        $el[0].click( function() {
        });

        setTimeout(function() {
            callBack();
        }, waitTime * 1000);


        $el[1].click( function() {
        });

    }
};
```

Comment: Your trying to reference the document that isn't in scope. Is this a server side script? Can you include the whole script? what other context can your provide?

Answer (score 0):

Simply call `.click()` on the jQuery selection result. The click function would apply to all items returned by the jQuery selection.

```
<script>
    $('h3 > a').click(function(){
        var aTagClicked = this;
    });
</script>
```

Comment: THanks, gave it a go. Accessed the same a elements but no tabs opened. Here are the h3>a contents: f.fn.init(20) [a#openInAliButton_117343788, a#openInAliButton_114731916, a#openInAliButton_114732004, a#openInAliButton_114730953, a#openInAliButton_114731076, a#openInAliButton_114728923, a#openInAliButton_114729276, a#openInAliButton_114724921, a#openInAliButton_114724671, a#openInAliButton_114724551, a#openInAliButton_114724523, a#openInAliButton_114715038, a#openInAliButton_114717048, a#openInAliButton_114716666, prevObject: f.fn.init(1), context: document, selector: "h3 > a"]

Comment: Same contents as in $el, but no new tab being opened.